# TypeScript: Inferring return type from a Decorator?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How do I get TypeScript to infer the Type of a decorated method when the decorator changes it's return type?

In the basic example below, I decorate a method to return a stringified object:

```
function jsonStringify() {
  return function (target, decoratedFnName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    let decoratedFn = descriptor.value;

    let newFn = function () {
      let object = decoratedFn.apply(target, arguments);

      return JSON.stringify(object);
    };

    descriptor.value = newFn;

    return descriptor;
  }
}

class Decorated {
  @jsonStringify()
  method(name: string, description: string) {
    return {
      name: name,
      description: description
    }
  }
};

let stringifiedObject = new Decorated().method('Test Name', 'Test Description');

console.log(stringifiedObject.includes('Test Name'));
```

If I transpile the TypeScript with `"noEmitOnError": false` in tsconfig.json, then the code runs perfectly and logs true to the console. However, tsc complains with the error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'includes' does not exist on type '{ name: string; description: string; }'.
```

Which I understand because `Decorated.method()` returns an object and not a string, but this method has a decorator which returns a string. What do I need to do to get TypeScript to infer the type from the decorator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not currently supported to change the return type of a function with a decorator.

There is an [open issue on github tracking this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881)

As an alternative, you could perhaps do something like this:

```
class Decorated {
  @jsonStringify()
  method(name: string, description: string): string | object {
    return {
      name: name,
      description: description
    };
  }
}

const stringifiedObject = new Decorated().method('Test Name', 'Test Description') as string;

console.log((stringifiedObject as string).includes('Test Name'));
```

but I recognise this is probably a bit of a departure from what you were looking for

Comment: Your solution isn't too bad in all honesty, it's just annoying more than anything to have such powerful functionality without Type support. I did come across that issue but I thought because it was old it might have been resolved and nobody updated it. In absence of a better answer in a few days I will most likely accept your answer.