# Is modifying method's return type by decorator possible?

Tags: typescript, decorator

Let's imagine that I have an `A` decorator that is being applied on a method that returns a string. The decorator uses that string and in the end returns `B` type (a class).

```
class B {
  constructor(text: string) { ... }

  method() {...}
}

class X {
  @A
  someMethod(): string {
    return 'lalala';
  }
}
```

decorator

```
function A(target, property, descriptor) {
  const text: string = descriptor.value();

  descriptor.value = () => new B(text);
}
```

What happened?  Now `someMethod` returns a `B` object instead of string. But I can't do something like this:

```
class X {
  constructor() {
    this.someMethod().method();
  }

  @A
  someMethod(): string {
    return 'lala';
  }
}
```

Why? Because `someMethod` from definition is of string type but the decorator makes it return `B` type. Can I in some way make the typescript know that `someMethod` in fact returns `B`, not `string`?

Comment: Here is similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927311/typescript-inferring-return-type-from-a-decorator?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**See below for 3.0 solution**

A decorator can't change the structure of the type, no type of decorator can do this (class, method or parameter decorators)

Using Typescript 2.8, you can write a function that will take another function as a parameter and perform a change of the return type, but you will loose things like parameter names, optional parameters and multiple signatures. Also you should take care, as this way of doing this makes `someMethod` a field that is assigned a method, instead of a class method. So the field will have to be assigned in each constructor instead of being assigned to the `prototype` once, this may have performance implications.

```
class B<T> {
    constructor(public value: T) { }

    method() { return this.value; }
}
function A<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: T): ReplaceReturnType<T, B<ReturnType<T>>> {
    return function (this: any, ...args: any[]) {
        return new B<ReturnType<T>>(fn.apply(this, args));
    } as any;
}

class X {
    constructor() {
        this.someMethod().method();
    }
    other() {}
    someMethod = A(function (this: X): string {
        this.other(); // We can access other members because of the explicit this parameter
        return 'lala';
    });
}
type IsValidArg<T> = T extends object ? keyof T extends never ? false : true : true;
type ReplaceReturnType<T, TNewReturn> = T extends (a: infer A, b: infer B, c: infer C, d: infer D, e: infer E, f: infer F, g: infer G, h: infer H, i: infer I, j: infer J) => infer R ? (
    IsValidArg<J> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H, i: I, j: J) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<I> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H, i: I) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<H> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<G> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<F> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<E> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<D> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<C> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<B> extends true ? (a: A, b: B) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<A> extends true ? (a: A) => TNewReturn :
    () => TNewReturn
) : never
```

**Edit**

Since the original question was answered typescript has improved the possible solution to this problem. With the addition of [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) we now don't need to have all the overloads for `ReplaceReturnType`:

```
type ArgumentTypes<T> = T extends (... args: infer U ) => infer R ? U: never;
type ReplaceReturnType<T, TNewReturn> = (...a: ArgumentTypes<T>) => TNewReturn;
```

Not only is this shorter but it solves a number of problems

- Optional parameters remain optional
- Argument names are preserved
- Works for any number of arguments

Sample:

```
type WithOptional = ReplaceReturnType<(n?: number)=> string, Promise<string>>;
let x!: WithOptional; // Typed as (n?: number) => Promise<string>
x() // Valid
x(1); //Ok
```

Comment: I think this solution makes `method()` a property of each instance object and not a prototype method, if it matters.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that is 100%, wanted to add that to the answer but forgot, I will add the note, 10x :)

Comment: @jcalz did you see this one ?, maybe yo have a better solution ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49427721/conditional-mapped-typed-with-unions-make-functions-uncallable