# Typescript: change function type so that it returns new value

Tags: typescript, recompose

Basically, I want something like this:

```
export type ReturnValueMapper<Func extends (...args: Args[] /* impossible */ ) => any, ReturnValue> = (...args: Args[]) => ReturnValue;
```

I'm almost sure that it's impossible, but I haven't found exact confirmation.

---

The use case is improving types for [recompose's withStateHandlers](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#withstatehandlers), enabling defining state updaters like this:

```
interface StateUpdaters {
    update(field: string): void; // I don't want to specify Partial<State> here 
}
```

Comment: You can do this in 2.8 I believe

Comment: The question isn't exactly a duplicate but check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49429420/2887218)

Comment: TS 2.8 lets you extract the return type of a function with `ReturnType<T>`, but I think to map the function signature you need [variadic types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453), which haven't been implemented.

Comment: @Aaron you do if you want a perfect solution, for a workable solution the answer @jcalz references does exactly that, using conditional types `ReplaceReturnType`in that answer replaces the return type.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Edit**

Since the original question was answered typescript has improved the possible solution to this problem. With the addition of [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) we now don't need to have all the overloads:

```
type ReplaceReturnType<T extends (...a: any) => any, TNewReturn> = (...a: Parameters<T>) => TNewReturn;
```

Not only is this shorter but it solves a number of problems

- Optional parameters remain optional
- Argument names are preserved
- Works for any number of arguments

Sample:

```
type WithOptional = ReplaceReturnType<(n?: number)=> string, Promise<string>>;
let x!: WithOptional; // Typed as (n?: number) => Promise<string>
x() // Valid
x(1); //Ok
```

***Original***

---

For a good solution you will need [variadic types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453), but for now this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429068/is-modifying-methods-return-type-by-decorator-possible/49429420#49429420) provides a workable solution. (Posting it here as the type there is used as part of a solution to a different question).

The basic idea is that we will extract the parameter types and recompose the function signature with the new return type. There are several disadvantages to this approach:

1. Parameter names are not preserved
2. Optional parameters are not handled well
3. Only works for a specific number of arguments (but more can be added as needed)

There may be other issues, but depending on your use-case this may be a good enough solution until the type system addresses this use case.

```
type IsValidArg<T> = T extends object ? keyof T extends never ? false : true : true;
type ReplaceReturnType<T, TNewReturn> = T extends (a: infer A, b: infer B, c: infer C, d: infer D, e: infer E, f: infer F, g: infer G, h: infer H, i: infer I, j: infer J) => infer R ? (
    IsValidArg<J> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H, i: I, j: J) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<I> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H, i: I) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<H> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<G> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<F> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<E> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<D> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<C> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<B> extends true ? (a: A, b: B) => TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<A> extends true ? (a: A) => TNewReturn :
    () => TNewReturn
) : never
```

---

The issue when used with optional parameters is that the optional parameter becomes required (and is of `type A | undefined`):

```
type WithOptional = ReplaceReturnType<(n?: number)=> string, Promise<string>>;

let x!: WithOptional;
x(); //invalid
x(undefined);
x(1);
```

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I need, thank you. However, I'm not sure what do you mean by "Optional parameters are not handled well", because I'm able to use them and can't see why they can possibly break. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @LeonidFenko added explanation of my cryptic warning :)

Comment: Oh, I got it. In my case I didn't notice it, because I never actually call functions with modified type. So it turns out to be a perfect solution for me.

Comment: The latest update does not seem to preserve the argument types in v3.0.1. It always ends up being `(...args: {}) => TNewReturn`, and using that to type a function will allow any arbitrary types for args.

Comment: Typescript now comes with `Parameters` which does what `ArgumentTypes` does in the answer

Comment: @WesleyT thanks for the ping on this answer, updated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with generic functions. Anything related to the generic in the signature is inferred as "unknown" - not sure why. [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShYBsCGBjCdgFcBOA7AKuBADz5QQAewEuAJgM5QAUAdG0gFxRK4gCUUALwA+brwA0UfADkIAdww5cowczYtOUAApJsSALYRq2eqWECRU2QqNKA3ACgHAM0y4UwAJYB7XFGe4ZkwUXPgCAN4OUNFQ2LZ4UBQOAL5OoJBQAOIAYm4oQrDwyGiKeISQxOkQ3s7+uJIARPTA2J64AOYNwkA) (edit: added playground link)