# How can we type a class factory that generates a class given an object literal?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

For example, I've made a JavaScript library called [`lowclass`](https://github.com/trusktr/lowclass) and I'm wondering how to make it work in the TypeScript type system.

The library lets us define a class by passing in an object-literal into the API, like the following, and I'm wondering how to make it return a type that is effectively the same as writing a regular `class {}`:

```
import Class from 'lowclass'

const Animal = Class('Animal', {
  constructor( sound ) {
    this.sound = sound
  },
  makeSound() { console.log( this.sound ) }
})

const Dog = Class('Dog').extends(Animal, ({Super}) => ({
  constructor( size ) {
    if ( size === 'small' )
      Super(this).constructor('woof')
    if ( size === 'big' )
      Super(this).constructor('WOOF')
  },
  bark() { this.makeSound() }
}))

const smallDog = new Dog('small')
smallDog.bark() // "woof"

const bigDog = new Dog('big')
bigDog.bark() // "WOOF"
```

As you can see, the `Class()` and `Class().extends()` API accept object literals used for defining classes.

How can I type this API so that the end result is that `Animal` and `Dog` behave in TypeScript as if I had written them using native `class Animal {}` and `class Dog extends Animal {}` syntax?

I.e., if I were to switch the code base from JavaScript to TypeScript, how might I type the API in this case so that the end result is that people using my classes made with lowclass can use them like regular classes?

EDIT1: It seems an easy way to type classes I make with lowclass by writing them in JavaScript and declaring regular `class {}` definitions inside of `.d.ts` type definitions files. It seems more difficult, if even possible, to convert my lowclass code base to TypeScript so that it can make the typing automatic when defining classes rather than make `.d.ts` files for every class.

EDIT2: Another idea that comes to mind is that I can leave lowclass as is (JavaScript typed as `any`), then when I define classes, I can just define them using `as SomeType` where `SomeType` can be a type declaration right inside the same file. This might be less DRY than making lowclass be a TypeScript library so that types are automatic, as I'd have to re-declare methods and properties that I've already defined while using the lowclass API.

Comment: Pretty sure you can make it very DRY with a generic. Something along the lines of `function Class<T extends object>(name: string, definition: T): ActualClass<T>`. The tricky part are the constructor's arguments. You might need some repeating there.

Comment: As for extending, I think it's too dynamic and too hack-y. TypeScript and metaprogramming don't play well together.

Comment: I think we can get decent typing., better than any or redeclaring all the types Not sure if I'll get to it tonight, but if nobody else gets to it, I'll answer it in the morning :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so there are several problems we need to fix for this to work in a similar way to Typescript classes. Before we begin, I do all of the coding below in Typescript `strict` mode, some typing behavior will not work without it, we can identify the specific options needed if you are interested in the solution.

### Type and value

In typescript classes hold a special place in that they represent both a value (the constructor function is a Javascript value) and a type. The `const` you define only represents the value (the constructor). To have the type for `Dog` for example we need to explicitly define the instance type of `Dog` to have it usable later:

```
const Dog =  /* ... */
type Dog = InstanceType<typeof Dog>
const smallDog: Dog = new Dog('small') // We can now type a variable or a field
```

### Function to constructor

The second problem is that `constructor` is a simple function, not a constructor function and typescript will not let us call a `new` on a simple function (at least not in strict mode). To fix this we can use a conditional type to map between the constructor and the original function. The approach is similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102620/typescript-new-class-by-evaluate-params/50103040#50103040) but I'm going to write it for just a few parameters to keep things simple, you can add more:

```
type IsValidArg<T> = T extends object ? keyof T extends never ? false : true : true;

type FunctionToConstructor<T, TReturn> =
    T extends (a: infer A, b: infer B) => void ?
        IsValidArg<B> extends true ? new (p1: A, p2: B) => TReturn :
        IsValidArg<A> extends true ? new (p1: A) => TReturn :
        new () => TReturn :
    never;
```

### Building the type

With the type above we can now create the simple `Class` function that will take in the object literal and build a type that looks like the declared class. If here is no `constructor` field, we will asume an empty constructor, and we must remove the `constructor` from the type returned by the new constructor function we will return, we can do this with `Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, 'constructor'>>`. We will also keep a field `__original` to have the original type of the object literal which will be useful later:

```
function Class<T>(name: string, members: T): FunctionToConstructor<ConstructorOrDefault<T>, Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, 'constructor'>>> & { __original: T  }


const Animal = Class('Animal', {
    sound: '', // class field
    constructor(sound: string) {
        this.sound = sound;
    },
    makeSound() { console.log(this.sound) // this typed correctly }
})
```

### This type in methods

In the `Animal` declaration above, `this` is typed correctly in the methods of the type, this is good and works great for object literals. For object literals `this` will have the type of the curent object in functions defined in the object literal. The problem is that we need to specify the type of `this` when extending an existing type, as `this` will have the members of the current object literal plus the members of the base type. Fortunately typescript lets us do this using `ThisType<T>` a marker type used by the compiler and described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/14141)

### Creating extends

Now using contextual this, we can create the `extends` functionality, the only problem to solve is we need to see if the derived class has it's own constructor or we can use the base constructor, replacing the instance type with the new type.

```
type ReplaceCtorReturn<T, TReturn> =
    T extends new (a: infer A, b: infer B) => void ?
        IsValidArg<B> extends true ? new (p1: A, p2: B) => TReturn :
        IsValidArg<A> extends true ? new (p1: A) => TReturn :
        new () => TReturn :
    never;
function Class(name: string): {
    extends<TBase extends {
        new(...args: any[]): any,
        __original: any
    }, T>(base: TBase, members: (b: { Super : (t: any) => TBase['__original'] }) => T & ThisType<T & InstanceType<TBase>>):
        T extends { constructor: infer TCtor } ?
        FunctionToConstructor<ConstructorOrDefault<T>, InstanceType<TBase> & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, 'constructor'>>>
        :
        ReplaceCtorReturn<TBase, InstanceType<TBase> & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, 'constructor'>>>
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
type IsValidArg<T> = T extends object ? keyof T extends never ? false : true : true;

type FunctionToConstructor<T, TReturn> =
    T extends (a: infer A, b: infer B) => void ?
    IsValidArg<B> extends true ? new (p1: A, p2: B) => TReturn :
    IsValidArg<A> extends true ? new (p1: A) => TReturn :
    new () => TReturn :
    never;

type ReplaceCtorReturn<T, TReturn> =
    T extends new (a: infer A, b: infer B) => void ?
    IsValidArg<B> extends true ? new (p1: A, p2: B) => TReturn :
    IsValidArg<A> extends true ? new (p1: A) => TReturn :
    new () => TReturn :
    never;

type ConstructorOrDefault<T> = T extends { constructor: infer TCtor } ? TCtor : () => void;

function Class(name: string): {
    extends<TBase extends {
        new(...args: any[]): any,
        __original: any
    }, T>(base: TBase, members: (b: { Super: (t: any) => TBase['__original'] }) => T & ThisType<T & InstanceType<TBase>>):
        T extends { constructor: infer TCtor } ?
        FunctionToConstructor<ConstructorOrDefault<T>, InstanceType<TBase> & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, 'constructor'>>>
        :
        ReplaceCtorReturn<TBase, InstanceType<TBase> & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, 'constructor'>>>
}
function Class<T>(name: string, members: T & ThisType<T>): FunctionToConstructor<ConstructorOrDefault<T>, Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, 'constructor'>>> & { __original: T }
function Class(): any {
    return null as any;
}

const Animal = Class('Animal', {
    sound: '',
    constructor(sound: string) {
        this.sound = sound;
    },
    makeSound() { console.log(this.sound) }
})

new Animal('').makeSound();

const Dog = Class('Dog').extends(Animal, ({ Super }) => ({
    constructor(size: 'small' | 'big') {
        if (size === 'small')
            Super(this).constructor('woof')
        if (size === 'big')
            Super(this).constructor('WOOF')
    },

    makeSound(d: number) { console.log(this.sound) },
    bark() { this.makeSound() },
    other() {
        this.bark();
    }
}))
type Dog = InstanceType<typeof Dog>

const smallDog: Dog = new Dog('small')
smallDog.bark() // "woof"

const bigDog = new Dog('big')
bigDog.bark() // "WOOF"

bigDog.bark();
bigDog.makeSound();
```

Hope this helps, let me know if I can help with anything more :)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Atype%20IsValidArg%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20object%20%3F%20keyof%20T%20extends%20never%20%3F%20false%20%3A%20true%20%3A%20true%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FunctionToConstructor%3CT%2C%20TReturn%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%09T%20extends%20(a%3A%20infer%20A%2C%20b%3A%20infer%20B)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3F%0D%0A%09IsValidArg%3CB%3E%20extends%20true%20%3F%20new%20(p1%3A%20A%2C%20p2%3A%20B)%20%3D%3E%20TReturn%20%3A%0D%0A%09IsValidArg%3CA%3E%20extends%20true%20%3F%20new%20(p1%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20TReturn%20%3A%0D%0A%09new%20()%20%3D%3E%20TReturn%20%3A%0D%0A%09never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ReplaceCtorReturn%3CT%2C%20TReturn%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%09T%20extends%20new%20(a%3A%20infer%20A%2C%20b%3A%20infer%20B)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3F%0D%0A%09IsValidArg%3CB%3E%20extends%20true%20%3F%20new%20(p1%3A%20A%2C%20p2%3A%20B)%20%3D%3E%20TReturn%20%3A%0D%0A%09IsValidArg%3CA%3E%20extends%20true%20%3F%20new%20(p1%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20TReturn%20%3A%0D%0A%09new%20()%20%3D%3E%20TReturn%20%3A%0D%0A%09never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ConstructorOrDefault%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20%7B%20constructor%3A%20infer%20TCtor%20%7D%20%3F%20TCtor%20%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20Class(name%3A%20string)%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09extends%3CTBase%20extends%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09new(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20any%2C%0D%0A%09%09__original%3A%20any%0D%0A%09%7D%2C%20T%3E(base%3A%20TBase%2C%20members%3A%20(b%3A%20%7B%20Super%3A%20(t%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20TBase%5B'__original'%5D%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20T%20%26%20ThisType%3CT%20%26%20InstanceType%3CTBase%3E%3E)%3A%0D%0A%09%09T%20extends%20%7B%20constructor%3A%20infer%20TCtor%20%7D%20%3F%0D%0A%09%09FunctionToConstructor%3CConstructorOrDefault%3CT%3E%2C%20InstanceType%3CTBase%3E%20%26%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20'constructor'%3E%3E%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3A%0D%0A%09%09ReplaceCtorReturn%3CTBase%2C%20InstanceType%3CTBase%3E%20%26%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20'constructor'%3E%3E%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Afunction%20Class%3CT%3E(name%3A%20string%2C%20members%3A%20T%20%26%20ThisType%3CT%3E)%3A%20FunctionToConstructor%3CConstructorOrDefault%3CT%3E%2C%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20'constructor'%3E%3E%3E%20%26%20%7B%20__original%3A%20T%20%7D%0D%0Afunction%20Class()%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20null%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20Animal%20%3D%20Class('Animal'%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%09sound%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%09constructor(sound%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.sound%20%3D%20sound%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%2C%0D%0A%09makeSound()%20%7B%20console.log(this.sound)%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Animal('').makeSound()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20Dog%20%3D%20Class('Dog').extends(Animal%2C%20(%7B%20Super%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%09constructor(size%3A%20'small'%20%7C%20'big')%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09if%20(size%20%3D%3D%3D%20'small')%0D%0A%09%09%09Super(this).constructor('woof')%0D%0A%09%09if%20(size%20%3D%3D%3D%20'big')%0D%0A%09%09%09Super(this).constructor('WOOF')%0D%0A%09%7D%2C%0D%0A%0D%0A%09makeSound(d%3A%20number)%20%7B%20console.log(this.sound)%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%09bark()%20%7B%20this.makeSound()%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%09other()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.bark()%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D))%0D%0Atype%20Dog%20%3D%20InstanceType%3Ctypeof%20Dog%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20smallDog%3A%20Dog%20%3D%20new%20Dog('small')%0D%0AsmallDog.bark()%20%2F%2F%20%22woof%22%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bigDog%20%3D%20new%20Dog('big')%0D%0AbigDog.bark()%20%2F%2F%20%22WOOF%22%0D%0A%0D%0AbigDog.bark()%3B%0D%0AbigDog.makeSound()%3B)

Comment: Holy moly, this is a whole 'nother form of programming (like programming the types). Thanks for this insight. No questions yet. Gotta go learn this meta typing.

Comment: @trusktr Yup it's another way of programming :) Fun fact, the typescript type system is Turing complete itself https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14833

Comment: Hi Titian, I've been learning from my other questions (thanks for other answers!), and am starting to better understand all of this now. The actual problem is a little more difficult. Here's a more complete picture of what the `Class()` API looks like in plain JS: http://trusktr.io:7777/ebisimokak.js. As you can see there, there are also static, private, and protected members which are defined in sub-objects. Is it possible to type those private/protected/static members as such?

Comment: That's quite impressive, I gotta say! A downside of this over regular classes is that when hovering over a variable (f.e. `bigDog`), it's not easy to understand the type tooltip. With regular classes, we'd see `const bigDog: Dog` in the tooltip, but in the playground example the tooltip shows: `const bigDog: Pick<{ sound: string; constructor(sound: string): void; makeSound(): void; }, "sound" | "makeSound"> & Pick<{ constructor(size: "small" | "big"): void; makeSound(d: number): void; bark(): void; other(): void; }, "makeSound" | ... 1 more ... | "other">`. I guess there's no way around that?

Comment: @trusktr I think we can improve things even on the tooltip side.. The statics and privates look doable at first glance (I just woke up, so take that with a grain of salt :P). Contact me on gitter, it's hard to have a conversation in comments and this will probably take a lot of back and forth to get right..