# How can I programmatically create class functions in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a log class that needs to define various convenience functions such as `error`, `warn`, `info`, etc that all do the same thing: make a call to a `log` function with their severity and the data to be logged.

This is verbose and wastes KBs:

```
class Logger {
  error(...args: any[]): void {
    this.log('error', ...args)
  }
  warn(...args: any[]): void {
    this.log('warn', ...args)
  }
  // ...and so on
}
```

I currently have an enum of all the severities, and a union of strings of all the severities:

```
enum severityLevels {
  error,
  warn,
  info
}

type severities = keyof typeof severityLevels
```

What I'd like to do is programmatically create functions for each severity level in the logger class's constructor (a very simple `Object.keys(severityLevels).forEach(...)` in vanilla JS), however I can't figure out how to get TypeScript to allow this to happen. If I make an interface with all the severity function definitions, I can't `implements` it (the functions don't already exist). If I make them optional, then calling those log functions (which "might not exist") gets messy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not have a single log function that takes in the severityLevel enum?

Comment: Just use the verbose version. The difference in payload size after gzipping is going to be trivial. The redundancy is the price you pay for type-safety. You could also try something like [this macro preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-transform-macros).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can programmatically add methods to a constructor's `prototype` in JavaScript and therefore in TypeScript.  The tricky part is getting the type system to understand what you're doing, which is doable but requires a bit of [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).

First, let's come up with an actual runtime list of those severities:

```
const severityKeys =
  Object.keys(SeverityLevels).filter(k => k !== (+k) + "") as Severities[];
```

Note, I init-capitalized the types to `SeverityLevels` and `Severities`, as per TS convention.  Also note that numeric `enum` objects in TypeScript also have reverse mappings: `Severities.error` is `0`, and `Severities[0]` is `"error"`.  To get the list of just the keys, I have to filter out the "numeric" keys with `k !== (+k)+""`.

Then, let's make an example `BaseLogger` class that represents your logger's functionality without the added methods:

```
class BaseLogger {
  constructor(public loggerName: string) {

  }
  log(level: string, ...args: any[]) {
    console.log("[" + this.loggerName + "]", "[" + level + "]", ...args);
  }
}
```

Here's how we might do the programmatic extension:

```
type Logger = BaseLogger & Record<Severities, (...args: any) => void>;
const Logger = (
  class Logger extends BaseLogger { }
) as new (...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof BaseLogger>) => Logger;
severityKeys.forEach(k => Logger.prototype[k] = function (this: Logger, ...args: any) {
  this.log(k, ...args);
})
```

This creates both a type and a value named `Logger`, so it is usable like a normal `class`.  The type corresponds to the type of the  *instances* of `Logger`, which look just like `BaseLogger` with the added method properties with keys in `Severities` and values of `(...args: any[])=>void`.

The value `Logger` is the *constructor* of `Logger` instances, which starts off as an empty extension of `BaseLogger` (although we *assert* that it constructs `Logger` instances).  After that we use `severityKeys.forEach()` to add the actual methods to `Logger.prototype` as needed.

Let's see if it works:

```
const logger = new Logger("My Logger");
logger.error(123); // [My Logger] [error] 123
logger.info(456); // [My Logger] [info] 456
logger.warn(789); // [My Logger] [warn] 789
```

Looks good to me.  All right, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYOwrgtgBAysBuwBOBLALgTwDIOAGwGcoBvAKCimSQHskAacqAdwEMkQGKUQAza0gL5RSmAA7BYuVGhTAiAXigBrYBmo8oY4OsmJp2XIVIBjaiAJooBKegwBpVQsYB5AEYArYMbQA6FRgIACjg9WxxEQgBKHx4UPDRkQKUoeQA+ZSgAQnlFQIBqJUioPKgAIlKiliIQ5HRZAgBtAF0AblJ24zwqogAhKuAsagBzIeQSRlNzNCQwb1pA0TBXPBRjKDxh0aQAORYIYAAuK2nuIaKyRgFGDaHAvEMji1QQIbooHw+2IYIjlhAMZrnRgUSYEaj3Hw3QKlBqlYqaAAWKAIkM2yF2+3hpSapTeMLhJXuESxOLeHx8XwIkTaFCuVxEGHEUEGIzGij61hZWygADIoAAlLy0AAmAB4atJ6m9AuTKb9-kU0lB4NQUMLUm1QZYuWyoIEJl0CEQdUhKAAPBIgYW9fomkhQK6VIggYBMPWypDfI4AYTMT1maFoAAU2HtgAkkARRVodByBmikKlFekTW1rKFMA4AjFaABRFjGBFJFIphM+UQ0QNaBpKJopKA8MAgbwoMx6tBIn7MhNkz6ert-DBAigd5Go25KXsU-vUwSRDp+yw3bmKF1uk3QgCyGG7rKQFTay+QPio8wAjAAmADM1KgAHo71AGtvd1s6w1T0g65er6Qj0gfG4PhAgAFgAVgANlvB8nxfE13yA6g63AiC-zLVh2ECAB2AAOABOaDH2fHd4KfDCQDrXC8PaUggA)

Comment: Wow, nice one! Bookmarking for study. There were two tricky (to me) TypeScript questions yesterday, this one and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59216833/157247) which still doesn't have an answer, if you feel like taking a swing at it...

Comment: added an answer there (with caveats)