# Typescript Proxyify Generic

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to wrap a base interface provided via a type generic so that each function in the interface has a modified return value.

For example:

```
interface IBaseInterface {
  test(a?: boolean, b?: number): Promise<boolean>;
  anotherTest?(a?: number): Promise<number>;
}

// to...

interface IBaseInterfaceModified {
  test(a?: boolean, b?: number): Promise<boolean> | string;
  anotherTest?(a?: number): Promise<number> | string;
}
```

I have tried to use mapped types with a combination of generics without any luck. The closest I have gotten is this:

```
type TProxyify<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: TProxy<T[K]>;
};

type ReturnType<T> = T extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : any;
type TProxy<T> = {
  (): ReturnType<T> | string;
};

export function wrapType<T>(): TProxyify<T> {
  return 1 as any;
}

const s = wrapType<IBaseInterface>();
// s.test() tooltip outputs -> test(): string | Promise<boolean>
```

However, the type suggestion system strips out the `BaseInterface.test` argument names and types. Is there anyway I can accomplish this so that I can wrap a base interface, modify the function return types, and still keep the original base interface type suggestions (argument names, types, and order) intact?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See below for 3.0 solution**

You can use a similar approach to the replace return type answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011616/typescript-change-function-type-so-that-it-returns-new-value/50014868#50014868)

```
type TProxyify<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: AddReturnType<T[K], string>;
};

type IsValidArg<T> = T extends object ? keyof T extends never ? false : true : true;
type AddReturnType<T, TNewReturn> = T extends (a: infer A, b: infer B, c: infer C, d: infer D, e: infer E, f: infer F, g: infer G, h: infer H, i: infer I, j: infer J) => infer R ? (
    IsValidArg<J> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H, i: I, j: J) => R | TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<I> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H, i: I) => R | TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<H> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H) => R | TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<G> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G) => R | TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<F> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F) => R | TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<E> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E) => R | TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<D> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D) => R | TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<C> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C) => R | TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<B> extends true ? (a: A, b: B) => R | TNewReturn :
    IsValidArg<A> extends true ? (a: A) => R | TNewReturn :
    () => R | TNewReturn
) : T

export function wrapType<T>(): TProxyify<T> {
    return 1 as any;
}

interface IBaseInterface {
    test(a?: boolean, b?: number): Promise<boolean>;
    anotherTest?(a?: number): Promise<number>;
}

const s = wrapType<IBaseInterface>();

let ss = s.test(undefined, undefined); // will be string | Promise<boolean>
```

The issue with this approach is that when used with optional parameters the optional parameter becomes required (and is of type A | undefined). This is why the call to test is `s.test(undefined, undefined);` and not `s.test();`

Also parameter names are not preserved which may be an issue with regard to readability.

**Edit**

Since the original question was answered typescript has improved the possible solution to this problem. With the addition of [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) we now don't need to have all the overloads:

```
type TProxyify<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: AddReturnType<T[K], string>;
};

type ArgumentTypes<T> = T extends (... args: infer U ) => any ? U: never;
type AddReturnType<T, TNewReturn> = T extends (...args: any[])=> infer R ? (...a: ArgumentTypes<T>) => TNewReturn | R : T;

export function wrapType<T>(): TProxyify<T> {
    return 1 as any;
}

interface IBaseInterface {
    test(a?: boolean, b?: number): Promise<boolean>;
    anotherTest?(a?: number): Promise<number>;
}

const s = wrapType<IBaseInterface>();

let ss = s.test(undefined, undefined); // will be string | Promise<boolean>
```

Not only is this shorter but it solves a number of problems

- Optional parameters remain optional
- Argument names are preserved
- Works for any number of arguments

Comment: There is no way to retain the argument names?

Comment: @Pat Nope ... that is the other problem, i forgot to mention :)

Comment: @Pat there is unfortunately no better solution at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the help!