# How to forward (well-known) symbols in a type wrapper (mapped type)?

Tags: typescript

Following the documentation on [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), it should be possible to have a wrapper like this in TypeScript:

```
export type Wrapped<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P];
} & { _state: number }

function wrap<T extends object>(x: T): Wrapped<T> {
  let xWrapped = x as Wrapped<T>
  xWrapped._state = 0;
  return xWrapped;
}
```

In general this seems to work well, a `Wrapped<T>` behaves exactly like `T`.

However, I noticed that there can be cases where the type system isn't happy. For instance:

```
let a = new Date()
let b = wrap(a)

function f(d: Date) {}

f(a) // works
f(b) // error: Property '[Symbol.toPrimitive]' is missing in type 'Wrapped<Date>' but required in type 'Date'
```

How can I write the type definition of `Wrapped<T>` to support types like `Date`?

---

**Background:** The actual issue behind this simplified example arises in [Solid (framework)](https://github.com/ryansolid/solid), which uses [a recursive version of such a wrapper](https://github.com/ryansolid/solid/blob/8fe0c11360387a325d64e040a756585a69f6da63/src/state.ts#L12-L14) for its core state handling. In this case, the problem is pretty severe, because TypeScript does not accept a `Wrapped<MyState>` for a `MyState` as soon as somewhere down in the nested state there is a "non-wrappable" type like `Date`, leading to `... as any as X` casts everywhere. The goal of this question is to make Solid more usable from TypeScript.

---

**What I tried:** I've been tinkering about this for a few weeks without success. The [2.9 release note](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html) mention that a mapped type `{ [P in K]: XXX }` now also support symbols, but I have no idea how that would look syntactically.

```
export type Wrapped<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P];
} & {
  [symbol in keyof T]?: T[symbol];  // doesn't work
} & { _state: number }
```

What does "work" is writing the wrapper as

```
export type Wrapped<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P];
} & { _state: number } & {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "string"): string;
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "default"): string;
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "number"): number;
}
```

but obviously I don't want to add these symbols to all wrapped types unconditionally. Basically I'm looking for the syntax that expresses "if a symbol is in T, add it to the wrapped type". If this isn't possible generically, is it at least possible to hard-code it for the set of well-known symbols?

I found a few issues on GitHub that may be related, but being a TypeScript beginner, I couldn't make much sense of them:

- [#1863 Allow indexing with symbols](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1863)
- [#24587 Type 'symbol' cannot be used as an index type.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24587)
- [#4538 Improve support for Symbol.toPrimitive](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4538)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types)

```
type AddSymbolToPrimitiveDefault<T> = T extends 
  {[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "default"): string;} ? 
  {[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "default"): string;} : {};

type AddSymbolToPrimitiveString<T> = T extends 
  {[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "string"): string;} ? 
  {[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "string"): string;} : {};

type AddSymbolToPrimitiveNumber<T> = T extends 
  {[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "number"): number;} ? 
  {[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "number"): number;} : {};


type AddSymbolToPrimitiveTString<T> = T extends 
  {[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: string): string | number;} ? 
  {[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: string): string | number;} : {};

export type Wrapped<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P];
} & { _state: number } & AddSymbolToPrimitiveDefault<T>
 & AddSymbolToPrimitiveString<T> & AddSymbolToPrimitiveNumber<T> & AddSymbolToPrimitiveTString<T>

function wrap<T extends object>(x: T): Wrapped<T> {
  let xWrapped = x as Wrapped<T>
  xWrapped._state = 0;
  return xWrapped;
}

let a = new Date()
let b = wrap(a);

function f(d: Date) {}

f(a); // works
f(b); // works too
```

**Update**
There is short solution suggested by @jcalz

```
type AddSymbolToPrimitive<T> = T extends 
  {[Symbol.toPrimitive]: infer V;} ? 
  {[Symbol.toPrimitive]: V;} : {};  

export type Wrapped<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P];
} & { _state: number } & AddSymbolToPrimitive<T>
```

Comment: I think you can replace all of those with just `type AddSymbolToPrimitive<T> = T extends { [Symbol.toPrimitive]: infer V; } ? { [Symbol.toPrimitive]: V } : {};`

Comment: There is another challenge, wrapping functions: `let a = () => { return "" }`. Is it also possible to generically inherit the call signature? Adding the conditional type `type Callable<T> = T extends {(): infer V;} ? {(): V;} : {};` makes it work for this particular function signature, but fails e.g. with `let a = (x: number) => { return "" }`.

Comment: Looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55055650/1804173) may solve that. I'm using now: `type AddCallable<T> = T extends {(...x: any[]): infer V;} ? {(...x: Parameters<T>): V;} : {};`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that [well-known symbols are not included as part of `keyof`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24622), and thus you can't map over them. That issue is confusingly marked as "fixed" but I think that's a mistake or misleading; its also marked as "fix available" which is true: [this pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24738) should address the problem if it ever gets merged.  The activity here looks recent enough (June 2019) that there's some reasonable chance of seeing it in the language in the not-too-distant future, but you might want to go over to those issues and give them  or describe your use cases if you think they are particularly compelling.

<strike>I don't have a great workaround for you since it's currently hard to detect these well-known symbol keys.  If you do any special-casing it will probably have to be of the types that have these symbols as keys, and not of the keys themselves.  Oh well.</strike> EDIT: @NailAchmedzhanov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57101132/2887218) looks like a plausible workaround to me.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks for explaining the background and pointing to the GitHub activities -- that would have been my follow-up question. Coincidentally, "fix available" was posted 3 days ago, good timing.