# How to get the type of a TS class member that's indexed with a well-known symbol like Symbol.toStringTag?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

What's the right TS syntax to extract the type of a class method that's indexed with a well-known `Symbol`?  Here's two ways that don't work:

```js
type T = String[Symbol.toStringTag];
// 'Symbol' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.(2702)
// Exported type alias 'T' has or is using private name 'Symbol'.(4081)

type U = String[Symbol['toStringTag']];
// Property 'toStringTag' does not exist on type 'Symbol'.(2339)
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDKwBOBLAdgcwNpJAFsAjAewBsA6YUlDHGAQ2wF0BuAKAHouoByAiQp8opTORBRUEAGYRUAZyg0ojZeAgAaKMQCuwKOiXEIWbFF0KIAE1VK1mRoQgKwjAMbQAFvIiUAFABMAOwADIEAlNy8AKIAHmCkqMA26pCq5OiMSnwwIl7ZoqiGSpZmUGAYAG6MKVCOzvyCZOR8AQAsoQAcAIxRHKDpAKoIyGhm+EQtuHw0dGZM2Hws7NFQAAqopJDJkrO04wzMItakLvWkBhBxRgZiadACU8IBgQDMbwCcEUA

Non-well-known symbols are unsupported in TS 4.1 (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797 should fix that) but according to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/1978 ES6 well-known symbols should be supported.

FYI: [How to forward (well-known) symbols in a type wrapper (mapped type)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100616/how-to-forward-well-known-symbols-in-a-type-wrapper-mapped-type) may provide some ideas to fix this, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Since the type of `SymbolConstructor.toStringTag` is just `symbol`, it's hard to use this as an index type. A conditional type helps:

```
type RetreiveToStringTag<T> = T extends { [Symbol.toStringTag]: infer V } ? V : never;
```

It says that if the object you're passing has `[Symbol.toStringTag]` defined, you infer the type and return it, otherwise, it's `never` (causing red squigglies in usage, not in type assignment. So:

```
type U = RetreiveToStringTag<Int16Array>
```

yields the string literal type `"Int16Array"`. However, bad news:

```
type U = RetreiveToStringTag<String>
```

yields `never`, as it seems that current `lib.d.ts` files don't have `[Symbol.toStringTag]` for `String` defined.