# Test throws errors TS2322 and TS2769 when adding an additional unused date field to a custom type

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using

- Pop!_OS 21.04 (Ubuntu)
- node v16.11.1
- npm v7.5.2
- Vue CLI v4.5.13

and want to create a Vue3 app using the [Pinia package](https://pinia.esm.dev/getting-started.html#installation) until Vuex5 will be ready. I run

```
vue create foo

# manually select TypeScript and Jest for unit tests

cd foo

npm install pinia
```

Inside the generated *example.spec.ts* file I setup a custom type, a sample store and a single test

```
import { defineStore, setActivePinia, createPinia } from "pinia";
import { computed, ComputedRef, ref, Ref } from "vue";

/*
    Define a custom type for demo purposes
*/
type MyValue = { isTrue: boolean };

/*
    Define the store using the composition API
*/
const useStore = defineStore("myValues", () => {
  const myValues: Ref<MyValue[]> = ref<MyValue[]>([]);

  const myTruthyValues: ComputedRef<MyValue[]> = computed<MyValue[]>(() =>
    myValues.value.filter((myValue: MyValue) => myValue.isTrue));

  return { myTruthyValues };
});

/*
    Use the store somewhere in the project
*/
describe("Store", (): void => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    setActivePinia(createPinia());
  });

  it("returns truthy values", (): void => {
    const myValuesStore = useStore();

    expect(myValuesStore.myTruthyValues.every((myValue: MyValue) => myValue.isTrue)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The test passes. But when changing the type definition of `MyValue` to `type MyValue = { isTrue: boolean; createdAt: Date; };` the test fails with

```
TypeScript diagnostics (customize using `[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics` option):
tests/unit/example.spec.ts:13:9 - error TS2322: Type 'Ref<{ isTrue: boolean; createdAt: { toString: () => string; toDateString: () => string; toTimeString: () => string; toLocaleString: { (): string; (locales?: string | string[] | undefined, options?: DateTimeFormatOptions | undefined): string; }; ... 39 more ...; getVarDate: () => VarDate; }; }[]>' is not assignable to type 'Ref<MyValue[]>'.
  Type '{ isTrue: boolean; createdAt: { toString: () => string; toDateString: () => string; toTimeString: () => string; toLocaleString: { (): string; (locales?: string | string[] | undefined, options?: DateTimeFormatOptions | undefined): string; }; ... 39 more ...; getVarDate: () => VarDate; }; }[]' is not assignable to type 'MyValue[]'.
    Type '{ isTrue: boolean; createdAt: { toString: () => string; toDateString: () => string; toTimeString: () => string; toLocaleString: { (): string; (locales?: string | string[] | undefined, options?: DateTimeFormatOptions | undefined): string; }; ... 39 more ...; getVarDate: () => VarDate; }; }' is not assignable to type 'MyValue'.
      Types of property 'createdAt' are incompatible.
        Property '[Symbol.toPrimitive]' is missing in type '{ toString: () => string; toDateString: () => string; toTimeString: () => string; toLocaleString: { (): string; (locales?: string | string[] | undefined, options?: DateTimeFormatOptions | undefined): string; }; ... 39 more ...; getVarDate: () => VarDate; }' but required in type 'Date'.

13   const myValues: Ref<MyValue[]> = ref<MyValue[]>([]);
           ~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts:114:5
    114     [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "default"): string;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '[Symbol.toPrimitive]' is declared here.
tests/unit/example.spec.ts:32:47 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(predicate: (value: { isTrue: boolean; createdAt: { toString: () => string; toDateString: () => string; toTimeString: () => string; toLocaleString: { (): string; (locales?: string | string[] | undefined, options?: DateTimeFormatOptions | undefined): string; }; ... 39 more ...; getVarDate: () => VarDate; }; }, index: number, array: { ...; }[]) => value is { ...; }, thisArg?: any): this is { ...; }[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(myValue: MyValue) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { isTrue: boolean; createdAt: { toString: () => string; toDateString: () => string; toTimeString: () => string; toLocaleString: { (): string; (locales?: string | string[] | undefined, options?: DateTimeFormatOptions | undefined): string; }; ... 39 more ...; getVarDate: () => VarDate; }; }, index: number, arr...'.
      Types of parameters 'myValue' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type '{ isTrue: boolean; createdAt: { toString: () => string; toDateString: () => string; toTimeString: () => string; toLocaleString: { (): string; (locales?: string | string[] | undefined, options?: DateTimeFormatOptions | undefined): string; }; ... 39 more ...; getVarDate: () => VarDate; }; }' is not assignable to type 'MyValue'.
          Types of property 'createdAt' are incompatible.
            Property '[Symbol.toPrimitive]' is missing in type '{ toString: () => string; toDateString: () => string; toTimeString: () => string; toLocaleString: { (): string; (locales?: string | string[] | undefined, options?: DateTimeFormatOptions | undefined): string; }; ... 39 more ...; getVarDate: () => VarDate; }' but required in type 'Date'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(predicate: (value: { isTrue: boolean; createdAt: { toString: () => string; toDateString: () => string; toTimeString: () => string; toLocaleString: { (): string; (locales?: string | string[] | undefined, options?: DateTimeFormatOptions | undefined): string; }; ... 39 more ...; getVarDate: () => VarDate; }; }, index: number, array: { ...; }[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): boolean', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(myValue: MyValue) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { isTrue: boolean; createdAt: { toString: () => string; toDateString: () => string; toTimeString: () => string; toLocaleString: { (): string; (locales?: string | string[] | undefined, options?: DateTimeFormatOptions | undefined): string; }; ... 39 more ...; getVarDate: () => VarDate; }; }, index: number, arr...'.
      Types of parameters 'myValue' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type '{ isTrue: boolean; createdAt: { toString: () => string; toDateString: () => string; toTimeString: () => string; toLocaleString: { (): string; (locales?: string | string[] | undefined, options?: DateTimeFormatOptions | undefined): string; }; ... 39 more ...; getVarDate: () => VarDate; }; }' is not assignable to type 'MyValue'.

32     expect(myValuesStore.myTruthyValues.every((myValue: MyValue) => myValue.isTrue)).toBeTruthy();
                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts:114:5
    114     [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "default"): string;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '[Symbol.toPrimitive]' is declared here.
```

The additional date field should not affect the test, although it seems to struggle with that type because an additional `number` field works fine.

Unfortunately I don't know what's wrong

- My code? (but the test passes without the date field)
- Vue provides a wrong TS config?
- Jest struggles with it?

I don't think this issue is related to Pinia...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of TypeScript, as described [in an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57101045/6277151). However, the [proposed solution there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57101132/6277151) does not work for some reason.

#### Option 1: Update `typescript` to 4.3+

The TypeScript issue is [fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42543) in 4.3, so perhaps the quickest solution is to update your `typescript` version:

```
npm i -D typescript@^4.4.3
```

#### Option 2: Omit `Symbol.toPrimitive`

If you prefer to keep the older version of `typescript`, you can omit `Symbol.toPrimitive` from `Date` for the `createdAt` property type:

```js
type MyValue = { isTrue: boolean, createdAt: Omit<Date, SymbolConstructor['toPrimitive']> };
```

#### Option 3: Use type inference

A workaround that avoids the type conflict is to *lean on type inference* instead of typing everything. In the example below, only the `myValues` `ref` is explicitly typed, while all related variable types are inferred :

```js
import { defineStore, setActivePinia, createPinia } from "pinia";
import { computed, ref } from "vue";

type MyValue = { isTrue: boolean; createdAt: Date; };

const useStore = defineStore("myValues", () => {
                        
  const myValues = ref<MyValue[]>([]);
             
  const myTruthyValues = computed(() =>
                             
  myValues.value.filter(myValue => myValue.isTrue));

  return { myTruthyValues };
});

describe("Store", (): void => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    setActivePinia(createPinia());
  });

  it("returns truthy values", (): void => {
    const myValuesStore = useStore();
                                                 
    expect(myValuesStore.myTruthyValues.every(myValue => myValue.isTrue)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```