# Creating a fluent, stateful builder using the TypeScript type system

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a builder which can  represent `builder.a().b().build()` or `builder.b().a().build()`, but not `builder.a().build()`, `builder.b().build()` or `builder.a().a().build()`, etc.

Obviously I can do the validation in the build method, but I would like the compiler  to hint at this (and for vs code to provide auto complete). I think the TS type system can represent this using mapped types, unions and intersections, but I can't quite figure it out.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Frame challenge: Are you sure you need a builder in typescript? Wouldn't an object literal (optionally passed to a build method) be just as typesafe, but easier to implement? Yes, I am aware that builders are common in languages such as java, where they are often used as a workaround for the lack of object literals, but seing that the typescript language offers objects literals out of the box, I wonder why you still need a fluent builder?

Comment: Very fair question, and in general I'm not a fan of builders in any language. In this very trivial example, the answer is, no, I do not need one. In my actual example it's useful to me to ensure that a very flexible component is called only in specific ways. Also, given TypeScript's very expressive type system, it seems like it should be easier to do than in Java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with the easiest part, the actual implementation. The class uses `this` as return type. The actual magic will happen using an additional type later on:

```js
class ConcreteBuilder {
  a(): this {
    return this;
  }

  b(): this {
    return this;
  }

  build(): string {
    return 'foo';
  }
}
```

Next we'll need a generic type where we can pass in a function type and it will exchange the return type for something else. You'll see why in a minute. I copied this code from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50014868/1903366):

```js
type ArgumentTypes<T> = T extends (... args: infer U) => infer R ? U: never;
type ReplaceReturnType<O, N> = (...a: ArgumentTypes<O>) => N;
```

Now it gets interesting, here's the `Builder` type I came up with:

```js
type Builder<K extends keyof ConcreteBuilder> = {
  [U in K]: U extends 'build' ? ConcreteBuilder[U] : ReplaceReturnType<
    ConcreteBuilder[U],
    Builder<Exclude<K, U> extends never ? 'build' : Exclude<K, U>>
  >
};
```

The type has a generic argument `K` which is restricted to being a key of `ConcreteBuilder`. This could be `'a'` or also `'a' | 'b' | 'build'`. We'll use this argument to determine which methods should be available in the resulting type.

For this we use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) that iterates over all keys in `K`. For each `U in K`, except the `build` method we modify the method's return type.

`ConcreteBuilder[U]` refers to the original function type of the method.

If we've reached the build method (`U extends 'build'`) we keep the original type from `ConcreteBuilder`. Otherwise we use `ReplaceReturnType` to preserve the original arguments but replace the return type with:

```js
Builder<Exclude<K, U> extends never ? 'build' : Exclude<K, U>>
```

Lot's to unpack here. So as you can see we're replacing the return type with `Builder`. The arguments to which, as discussed, define what methods are available. Since this is the return type of method `U`, we want to remove `U` from the list of available methods to prevent calling it twice. This is done using the [`Exclude` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu). In our case we remove `U` from the union of keys `K`.

Because this recursive type goes on until all methods are removed from `K` we also need a base case. That's what the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) here is for. We check if the remaining keys (`Exclude<K, U>`) extend `never` which essentially means if the is "empty". And if that's the case return a builder with the method `build`.

Finally, the only thing left is the `builder` function:

```js
function builder(): Builder<Exclude<keyof ConcreteBuilder, 'build'>> {
  return new ConcreteBuilder() as any;
}
```

It returns a `Builder` with all methods except `build`. There is an `any` cast necessary, because the type of `ConcreteBuilder` is less restrictive than `Builder`.

---

#### Full code

```js
type ArgumentTypes<T> = T extends (... args: infer U) => infer R ? U: never;
type ReplaceReturnType<O, N> = (...a: ArgumentTypes<O>) => N;

type Builder<K extends keyof ConcreteBuilder> = {
  [U in K]: U extends 'build' ? ConcreteBuilder[U] : ReplaceReturnType<
    ConcreteBuilder[U],
    Builder<Exclude<K, U> extends never ? 'build' : Exclude<K, U>>
  >
};

function builder(): Builder<Exclude<keyof ConcreteBuilder, 'build'>> {
  return new ConcreteBuilder() as any;
}

class ConcreteBuilder {
  a(): this {
    return this;
  }

  b(): this {
    return this;
  }

  build(): string {
    return 'foo';
  }
}

builder().a().b().build(); // ok
builder().b().a().build(); // ok
builder().build(); // error
builder().a().build(); // error
builder().b().build(); // error
builder().a().a().build(); // error
builder().b().b().build(); // error
builder().a().b().b().build(); // error
builder().a().a().b().build(); // error
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwK4FsIDtgBVwQM4A8WAfFALxRZQQAewGAJnlABQB0HUAhongFxQAlugBmEOFACqASnKlhYiQCUoAfikD0EAG7iA3AChQkKEohgANlwDGEM8CRx0OSAQDyAGigA5UhXYcXALwyGiYLvjuxLJkpN6GRrhQAEJIghYM4gQA0tR0jMwA1hAgAPYiUADCpejWcBD0qemZcH5QAN4GUFAA2pJC6FDZALoC-bT06ExQAOQARmkZM2pVNXUNEE0Z4n3DUAJmljZ2DY7OuARd3au19Y2LLbseV91bLQQAojTWFkiZOV5JKQJgUoFpdBJ1PMHssBF8fn8IACpMRiFc0QBfBIiJC1YCCGpQBbNcQsaQCN5ZeG-f7FMoVaq3DaUuBeaHNGaojpXO5nMEQADuN3W9xJcDJ3GYXHQIEMGIMBh+XDwzEZIs2D3E3O6XDJAmAAAtBMxOtcoLynFBDcbDN15Vc5nqrUaTS9zadLda8LaoPbusSMk68MA4MIENrrhbBjMRKVSjMffL7QGWmS2LrpGxHZmU2S9FAAPQFqClQoGFOknNpjNZh55wvF0vlzXinN16T5ovUOBwUpwZti6tp3Mdhvd3v9iutrPD9ud4viCcD7bTms1kfz8d95epqt72vNetdxfbqdD-fZg+B0fHnunlvn9PD2eHm8Lu9wIA)

Comment: This is awesome. Only one issue I see... First, I'm seeing that the return type of .build() is Builder<"build">, so `builder().b().a().build().build().build(); // ok`. I guess it's because the ReplaceReturnType gets applied to the build() method too. I am trying to work through this and understand it, but I haven't reached the point where I can fix it yet:(

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that. I've fixed it by introducing another conditional in `Builder` which checks for the build method. See the updated answer.