# Decorator in Typescript to return timing of function

Tags: typescript, javascript-decorators

Usecase: I want to get how much time a function takes to execute in typescript. I want to use decorator for this purpose.
I want the decorator should return the time so that (I can further use it),   not just print it.
For eg :

```
export function createTimestamps(message: string) {
  return function (target: any, name: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const method = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = async function () {
      const startTime = new Date(Date.now());
      console.log(
        `${message} started at: ${startTime.toLocaleString("en-GB")}`
      );
      await method.apply(this);
      const endTime = new Date(Date.now());
      console.log(
        `${message} completed at: ${endTime.toLocaleString("en-GB")}`
      );
      console.log(
        `${message} took ${
          endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()
        }ms to complete.`
      );
    };
  };
}
```

If I use above function as decorator , then I would like the decorator to return "endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()" , so that I can further use it .

```
@creaTimestamp
async newfunc():string{
 return "typescript";
}
```

Now when I call above function await newfunc(). Can I get execution time value as well along with the string it is returning ?

Also I have many functions I want to avoid adding decorator on top of each one of them, and thus while calling them I want make sure that the decorator runs and returns the timing as well. Can someone point me to such library if exist ?

Can someone please share some insight in above scenarios, I am very new to decorators. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more info? How exactly do you expect to use the decorator, and what do you expect the result to be? Post some examples as code, even if you know they aren't correct. Also this may be close to what you want? https://leefreeman.xyz/2020/05/08/typescript-decorators/

Comment: Thanks for the link . So in the above link I would like the fucntion 'timer' to return 'runtime' along with 'value'? is it possible?

Comment: Well, you can certainly replace the return value of the method to be [actualResult, time] in the decorator, but that would violate type safety. What I would do is to use Reflect.defineMetafata in the decorator and store the last execution time in the method's metadata. Then you could retrieve it later in code using Reflect.getMetadata.

Comment: @Papooch Can you please give example?

Comment: @simeon I think Alex gave an excellent example of what was in my mind. To address your second concern regarding *I have many functions I want to avoid adding decorator on top of each one of them*, I'll go agead and shamelessly plug my [decorate-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decorate-all) package which I made exactly for that purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Returning* additional data is not possible with *typescript* decorators.

The main problem is that [a typescript decorator cannot change the return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429068/is-modifying-methods-return-type-by-decorator-possible) of a function. And a function can only return one value.

So, why is that important?

For example:

```
class Foo {
  async newfunc(): string {
    return "typescript";
  }
}

const lang = await new Foo().newFunc()
console.log(`${lang} is a cool language`)
```

In this example `lang` is a `string`, and your program expects it to be a `string`. If you then put the decorator on this function, and you expect that return a string *as well as* timing information, you'd have to return something like:

```
{ result: returnValueOfFunctionHere, elapsed: elapsedMsHere }
```

But that's not a `string` anymore. Now you'd have to drill into the `result` property to get that string. That means you've changed the return type of your function by applying the decorator. And that's not allowed at the moment.

This is the reason that example logs the info to the console rather than returning it.

---

But as @Papooch suggests, you can stash the elapsed time in *metadata* via `reflect-metadata`. You'd store this on a unique metadata key on the function being measured.

`reflect-metadata` is a useful package for things like this. Read more on [how to use it here](https://medium.com/jspoint/introduction-to-reflect-metadata-package-and-its-ecmascript-proposal-8798405d7d88#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFiZjhhODRkM2VjZDc3ZTlmMmFkNWYwNmZmZDI2MDcwMWRkMDZkOTAiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.fV2t4ndS1tmvwtTYL3A0Wcq7ufq79WrfOYKiHc-UANpjFnJF3wI3AQPRfSmc4x35cnySmQZ95L80Mb9VrpcFicAaMG58XCtkT9eIlj6HXdgOCu03K5kgVwgfEPMuDHkTJ2vGLLOKKklQvYpjUcQawZhKQ1ZTJzJjdQUozPJSUR-H6oTDfo94luBtrQe_o4G0QtObMfi-0uebRBRZtNyc61fnzd5zmTk_0yaYCu-YZg_pyYZq0lDEi1ZwoXJJIc_UXsuntfm0wsaiYBK98CRO7ayOMfIVRNPsPSwYzvCJL-5N3ic6_rD71WiiAG10-6GWzth5SwfX0Dy9cFkvYKrR8A).

```
import 'reflect-metadata'

// Create a key to store the metadata under. This should be a symbol.
const lastCallElapsedKey = Symbol('lastCallElapsedKey')

function createTimestamps(message: string) {
  return function (target: any, name: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const method = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = async function () {
      const startTime = new Date(Date.now());      
      const result = await method.apply(this);
      const endTime = new Date(Date.now());
      const elpased = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()

      // Write the elpased time to the new function's metadata.
      Reflect.defineMetadata(lastCallElapsedKey, elpased, descriptor.value)
      
      return result
    };
  };
}

// Get the elapsed time from the metadata.
function getElapsed(fn: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown): number | undefined {
    return Reflect.getMetadata(lastCallElapsedKey, fn)
}

class Foo {
    // Emulate an async call
    @createTimestamps("test")
    async newfunc(): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => resolve('typescript'), 250)
        })
    }
}

async function test() {
    const foo = new Foo()
    console.log(await foo.newfunc())
    console.log(getElapsed(foo.newfunc)) // 250
}
test()
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/PTAEEsFsAcHsCcAuoDk8CmAzANugxogLSTqICGAJmeSqCKAO7jbajTywBGZn2AnqE7pQAO3ToKEiCNB9YAV3hsOAc3hlIAKE30AwhmrCyoANboBiWKADOljKEQALYSXJVyoeSMnwAdJrxYEVtQbDJbXTIWAFEw6GsJAGlzUABeUABlPkhOWGwAChQwiKjsWLJ4pPMUAEptTC8CcCDQPANEdAAVKHRbDXj8kmtrMhV0AC4bRHhwERUa0ABvTVBQDERFGQaRJpb88ngxxEmyET4AGlENCamZucvJazbwaDtJgAUOaHQkPgARXrPV4IBbLVarQLBZCuRywChpUCPIF2XwANyi8nQAG5tODEYCZsC-OjsJiEeE+DtQNtdjJ8qCVnjWkEQn0kN0SAixAxQH9DPk+R1fCJYAx6TUsUzQIy8ZCQhhrPJsMh0mQGGRwNDSLCKL4KtB+PtHOBrBKZeC5ch0N4OcJ0tzefzBehhaLxTipZbQOhsNBwlJ0taKLbfEdbfTQIQpmR2T1Q6Rw3Vzat6AB1GYdBzOb2+-3wxA9BxWJzCB00gtBFDWUCuSjUMj+KUAJSwuAIvkkmFm6AAsqQ6+R8sVEJEYnEEhRkhcc36Jw8CS8USTMXUpcm1qRNhvFcrzQBfD2gA+aPfaegAcVIWeEPoqE4chcwHEg15r-fcDc05eaMiO5UqFD5JgIiTPkvjgTGKjWJMXgmCKDAiAA2gAugsqQAHyeCIcGiiINSTCI8g5D8oAAD5YZ23bwmC4LrFuLY4PgiDxogfZuPWQ7hCOpT-hOU6XMBdSngExTVgAYrAVg0SmYDRJASqGKApxKdYlJ4K0pTmgAAm06CGLafQwNY+QAEQdLYJmruCFJUtyNL0h8z4mugAA8th3ComHSUydHwDIDqfLAkDOfkCp5KidpeeuUoJIgtoKIg+QRhh27heghSIHw3xPISiC1JcABMACsAAMVlSnu5VHie2g2ep34tOZiUMrKLLIJgklcugPISbA9LmnKeQutgsAqPkaoau1knCt19k1FVg24L4I1jX+44SEB012Y0810GAxUlTVTX9UAA)

Comment: Thanks a ton thats so helpful !!

Comment: @simeon Glad I could help! I also just wanted to mention that your question about applying the decorator to many functions without having to declare it on each one deserves it's own question entirely. Good luck there :)